# not able to install g++ and gcc on debian

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies, g++

I want to use directadmin as my web control panel and it needs several packages like
g++ , gcc and etc...

as usuall I started to type apt-get install g++ and there problems start :

dependecy error...

then I tried to apt-get -f install and I got this error

> (Reading database ... 15140 files and
>   directories currently installed.)
>   Removing libc6-xen ... ldconfig:
>   /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc6-xen.conf:6:
>   hwcap index 0 already defined as
>   nosegneg dpkg: error processing
>   libc6-xen (--remove):  subprocess
>   post-removal script returned error
>   exit status 1 Errors were encountered
>   while processing:  libc6-xen E:
>   Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an
>   error code (1)

what shoud I do?
I want to install g++ and all of its dependencies due to using of directadmin I need it.

regards.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-get update
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get install libc6-xen
apt-get -f install
```

You have some partially installed packages and it is trying to remove libc6-xen.  If this is a xen vps, that is probably a rather fatal issue.  The above should get you back to a workable state.

Once you get things back to a reasonable state with that, try:

```
apt-get install libc6-xen g++
```

Don't proceed.  It will probably tell you that it needs to remove something due to some dependency.  Simplest solution is probably to run:

```
apt-get -f -u upgrade
```

and possibly

```
apt-get -f -u dist-upgrade
```

to get the machine to a clean state, then, try installing g++.  Watch the messages very carefully as it probably tried to install g++ and said it was going to remove something -- probably libc6-xen.  It might have said something like:  removing libc6-xen, no available packages.

Get your machine's dependencies fixed, then post the text from:

```
apt-get install libc6-xen g++
```

Comment: hi , thanks for your advice I've done what u said here and here is the result of executing apt-get install libc6-xen g++ :
(I will post it in next comment)

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  g++: Depends: cpp (>= 4:4.4.2-3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gcc (>= 4:4.4.2-3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: g++-4.4 (>= 4.4.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gcc-4.4 (>= 4.4.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
  locales: Depends: glibc-2.7-1
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: and yes I have vps which is created by xen , so is it possible for me to isntall these packages??? i mean g++ gcc and so no?
regards.

Comment: does apt-get -f install finish?  if not, do   dpkg --purge g++  then run apt-get -f install.  Once that finishes, you should be able to upgrade and figure out why your dependencies cannot be installed.  Something has gone wrong somewhere with your installation -- getting it to a working state and then figuring out what went wrong is the next step.  I don't see any reason why you can't, but, it might be that you have something held, preventing g++ from being installed.  Get the machine to a clean state, then, post what happens when you try to install g++

Comment: hi,I solve it , this is a known bug in kernel I've read about that in a mailing-list and it was indicated as bug #518133  there is a config file called libc6-xen.conf inside /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ and value of that should be 0 not 1.

Comment: If there is a config file, then just edit that file.